# How to increment datetime by custom months in python without using library

Tags: python, datetime

I need to increment the month of a datetime value

```
next_month = datetime.datetime(mydate.year, mydate.month+1, 1)
```

when the month is 12, it becomes 13 and raises error "month must be in 1..12". (I expected the year would increment)

I wanted to use timedelta, but it doesn't take month argument.
There is [relativedelta](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) python package, but i don't want to install it just only for this.
Also there is a solution using [strtotime](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/timelib/0.2).

```
time = strtotime(str(mydate));
next_month = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month", time));
```

I don't want to convert from datetime to str then to time, and then to datetime; therefore, it's still a library too

Does anyone have any good and **simple** solution just like using timedelta?

Comment: This is a shortcoming of python's `datetime` which must be able to do `datetime.timedelta(months=6)`. Java's [LocalDate.plusMonths()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/time/LocalDate.java#LocalDate.plusMonths%28long%29) increments the month and then ensures a valid date by decrementing the day field to the last valid date in the month. Python should do the same ootb without having to resort to external modules, but until it's fixed the java code can be easily ported — in fact it's roughly the same as the code in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

**Edit** - based on your comment of dates being needed to be rounded down if there are fewer days in the next month, here is a solution:

```
import datetime
import calendar

def add_months(sourcedate, months):
    month = sourcedate.month - 1 + months
    year = sourcedate.year + month // 12
    month = month % 12 + 1
    day = min(sourcedate.day, calendar.monthrange(year,month)[1])
    return datetime.date(year, month, day)
```

In use:

```
>>> somedate = datetime.date.today()
>>> somedate
datetime.date(2010, 11, 9)
>>> add_months(somedate,1)
datetime.date(2010, 12, 9)
>>> add_months(somedate,23)
datetime.date(2012, 10, 9)
>>> otherdate = datetime.date(2010,10,31)
>>> add_months(otherdate,1)
datetime.date(2010, 11, 30)
```

Also, if you're not worried about hours, minutes and seconds you could use `date` rather than `datetime`.  If you are worried about hours, minutes and seconds you need to modify my code to use `datetime` and copy hours, minutes and seconds from the source to the result.

Comment: if it was the 31st October, then it would be the 30st November

Comment: but i think the month may overflow here --> month = (sourcedate.month - 1 + months) % 12 + 1. Don't you think it's better to solve year after calculating the month?

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment.  The modulus prevents the month from overflowing and in the code it doesn't matter which order year and month are calculated.

Comment: I think for this instance add_months(date, 23), the year wouldn't increment more than 1. Anyway it solved my problem, perhaps it will solve others' such problems. Thanks a lot

Comment: i need the hours, minutes, and secs. coz later i need to compare it with a datetime value. but you don't need to edit for this. It's already clear

Comment: when the date was => d = datetime.date(2010, 11, 9) and if i increment by 23days => add_months(d, 23). the result comes datetime.date(2011, 10, 9).  Wouldnt be datetime.date(2012, 10, 9)
 ??

Comment: @zomboid - You're right - the year increment is horribly broken. Will fix in a bit.

Comment: @zomboid - Year calculation now fixed.

Comment: To easily make this work for date or datetime values, just change the last line to `return sourcedate.replace(year, month, day)`

Comment: In my case, I still wanted it to be a datetime, but I just wanted for it to be the end of the day.  If that's the case for you, you can change it to: `return datetime(year, month, day, 23, 59, 59)`

Comment: No module named Calender ? what should I do ?

Comment: @Sagar you need to import datetime

Comment: The year calculation will come up with an float result if the month is not divisible by 12. The following resolved this for me.

year = int(sourcedate.year + month / 12)

Comment: The day determination returns IMO incorrect values if we assume that adding 1 month to last day of month should return last day of next month. Example: `d = datetime.date(2015, 2, 28); add_months(d, 1)` will produce `datetime.date(2015, 3, 28)` instead of `datetime.date(2015, 3, 31)`

Comment: It's not wrong, but it's not the simplest solution either. Please, take note of "Atul Arvind" answer below.

Comment: For year addition, that will follow the same rules, just add a wrapper to this like `def addYearsToDate( d, years ): return addMonthsToDate( d, years*12 )`

Comment: This solution needs parentheses. This line `month = sourcedate.month - 1 + months` is unreadable.

Comment: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'

Answer (score 603):

This is short and sweet method to add a month to a date using [dateutil's `relativedelta`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil).

```py
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
    
date_after_month = datetime.today()+ relativedelta(months=1)
print('Today: ',datetime.today().strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
print('After Month:', date_after_month.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
```

```
Today:  01/03/2013

After Month: 01/04/2013
```

**A word of warning**: `relativedelta(months=1)` and `relativedelta(month=1)` have [different meanings](http://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/relativedelta.html). Passing `month=1` will **replace** the month in original date to January whereas passing `months=1` will add one month to original date.

Note: this will require `python-dateutil` module. If you are on Linux you need to run this command in the terminal in order to install it.

```sh
sudo apt-get update && sudo pip install python-dateutil
```

Explanation : [Add month value in python](http://pythoninspire.blogspot.com/2013/08/add-month-value-in-python.html)

Comment: This requires the [`python-dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) module, though/

Comment: you could also use `pip install --user python-dateutil` if you can't install the package globally (or you want a different version).

Comment: What is the difference between timedelta and relativedelta in the dateutil package?

Comment: Does dateutil play nicely with pytz-aware datetimes (dt localized with pytz tzinfo)?

Comment: @Fomalhaut It's month**s**, not just month. What a way to make a library vulnerable to buggy behaviour.

Comment: could you please provide source code for finding yesterday

Comment: months and month save me for more than 3 hours of debugging

Comment: `datetime.today()+ relativedelta(months=12)` never increments to the next year

Comment: Using `relativedelta` with a localised datetime seem to result in the tzinfo being removed which is unfortunate.

Answer (score 52):

Here's my salt :

```
current = datetime.datetime(mydate.year, mydate.month, 1)
next_month = datetime.datetime(mydate.year + int(mydate.month / 12), ((mydate.month % 12) + 1), 1)
```

Quick and easy :)

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem: it takes you to the first day of the next month, not the 'same day'. Of course you could change the "1" to mydate.day, but then you risk an error when you go e.g. from Jan 31 to Feb.

Comment: That doesn't fully solve the OP's problem, but it does work for my case.

Comment: `next_month = datetime(year+1 if month == 12 else year, 1 if month == 12 else month)`

Comment: Pure awesomeness!!!

Answer (score 21):

since no one suggested any solution, here is how i solved so far

```
year, month= divmod(mydate.month+1, 12)
if month == 0: 
      month = 12
      year = year -1
next_month = datetime.datetime(mydate.year + year, month, 1)
```

Comment: nice, pretty much the same in less code. thats a win.

Comment: Although, this doesn't solve the problem: it takes you to the first day of the next month, not the 'same day'.

Comment: @MatthewSchinckel You could just replace the `1` at the end by the current day, but then you would need to check for 31/30 days (not talking about February)

Answer (score 14):

Use the [monthdelta](http://packages.python.org/MonthDelta/) package, it works just like timedelta but for calendar months rather than days/hours/etc.

Here's an example:

```
from monthdelta import MonthDelta

def prev_month(date):
    """Back one month and preserve day if possible"""
    return date + MonthDelta(-1)
```

Compare that to the DIY approach:

```
def prev_month(date):
    """Back one month and preserve day if possible"""
   day_of_month = date.day
   if day_of_month != 1:
           date = date.replace(day=1)
   date -= datetime.timedelta(days=1)
   while True:
           try:
                   date = date.replace(day=day_of_month)
                   return date
           except ValueError:
                   day_of_month -= 1
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution.

Comment: If I have to install a different package, I'd rather take `python-dateutil`

Comment: I needed to use `monthdelta.monthdelta(-1)`.

Answer (score 13):

```
from datetime import timedelta
try:
    next = (x.replace(day=1) + timedelta(days=31)).replace(day=x.day)
except ValueError:  # January 31 will return last day of February.
    next = (x + timedelta(days=31)).replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)
```

If you simply want the first day of the next month:

```
next = (x.replace(day=1) + timedelta(days=31)).replace(day=1)
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the second example would fail on January 21st, and send you right into March.

Comment: `x.replace(day=1)` switches Jan 21 to Jan 1 before adding 31 days.

Answer (score 10):

To calculate the current, previous and next month:

```
import datetime
this_month = datetime.date.today().month
last_month = datetime.date.today().month - 1 or 12
next_month = (datetime.date.today().month + 1) % 12 or 12
```

Comment: Much shorter `next_month = datetime.date.today().month % 12 + 1`

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps add the number of days in the current month using calendar.monthrange()?

```
import calendar, datetime

def increment_month(when):
    days = calendar.monthrange(when.year, when.month)[1]
    return when + datetime.timedelta(days=days)

now = datetime.datetime.now()
print 'It is now %s' % now
print 'In a month, it will be %s' % increment_month(now)
```

Comment: increment_month(datetime.date(2011,1,31)) -> datetime.date(2011, 3, 3), which rounds the wrong way.

Answer (score 6):

What about this one? (doesn't require any extra libraries)

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
from calendar import monthrange

today = date.today()
month_later = date(today.year, today.month, monthrange(today.year, today.month)[1]) + timedelta(1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Simplest solution is to go at the end of the month (we always know that months have at least 28 days) and add enough days to move to the next moth:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> today = datetime.today()
>>> today
datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 30, 11, 47, 27, 811253)
>>> (today.replace(day=28) + timedelta(days=10)).replace(day=today.day)
datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 30, 11, 47, 27, 811253)
```

Also works between years:

```
>>> dec31
datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 31, 11, 47, 27, 811253)
>>> today = dec31
>>> (today.replace(day=28) + timedelta(days=10)).replace(day=today.day)
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 31, 11, 47, 27, 811253)
```

Just keep in mind that it is not guaranteed that the next month will have the same day, for example when moving from 31 Jan to 31 Feb it will fail:

```
>>> today
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 31, 11, 47, 27, 811253)
>>> (today.replace(day=28) + timedelta(days=10)).replace(day=today.day)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

So this is a valid solution if you need to move to the first day of the next month, as you always know that the next month has day **1** (`.replace(day=1)`). Otherwise, to move to the last available day, you might want to use:

```
>>> today
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 31, 11, 47, 27, 811253)
>>> next_month = (today.replace(day=28) + timedelta(days=10))
>>> import calendar
>>> next_month.replace(day=min(today.day, 
                               calendar.monthrange(next_month.year, next_month.month)[1]))
datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 29, 11, 47, 27, 811253)
```

Answer (score 4):

Similar in ideal to Dave Webb's solution, but without all of that tricky modulo arithmetic:

```
import datetime, calendar

def increment_month(date):
    # Go to first of this month, and add 32 days to get to the next month
    next_month = date.replace(day=1) + datetime.timedelta(32)
    # Get the day of month that corresponds
    day = min(date.day, calendar.monthrange(next_month.year, next_month.month)[1])
    return next_month.replace(day=day)
```

Comment: This is about twice as slow as Dave's solution.

Answer (score 4):

This implementation might have some value for someone who is working with billing.

If you are working with billing, you probably want to get "the same date next month (if possible)" as opposed to "add 1/12 of one year".

What is so confusing about this is you actually need take into account two values if you are doing this continuously. Otherwise for any dates past the 27th, you'll keep losing a few days until you end up at the 27th after leap year.

The values you need to account for:

- The value you want to add a month to
- The day you started with

This way if you get bumped from the 31st down to the 30th when you add one month, you'll get bumped back up to the 31st for the next month that has that day.

This is how I did it:

```
def closest_date_next_month(year, month, day):
    month = month + 1
    if month == 13:
        month = 1
        year  = year + 1


    condition = True
    while condition:
        try:
            return datetime.datetime(year, month, day)
        except ValueError:
            day = day-1
        condition = day > 26

    raise Exception('Problem getting date next month')

paid_until = closest_date_next_month(
                 last_paid_until.year, 
                 last_paid_until.month, 
                 original_purchase_date.day)  # The trick is here, I'm using the original date, that I started adding from, not the last one
```

Answer (score 3):

Well with some tweaks and use of [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) here we go:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def inc_date(origin_date):
    day = origin_date.day
    month = origin_date.month
    year = origin_date.year
    if origin_date.month == 12:
        delta = datetime(year + 1, 1, day) - origin_date
    else:
        delta = datetime(year, month + 1, day) - origin_date
    return origin_date + delta

final_date = inc_date(datetime.today())
print final_date.date()
```

Comment: incerement by 4 weeks (28 days)?  Months have different days, haven't they?

Comment: ah good point. i'll drop this and think about it more.

Comment: Don't think this will work when the next month has fewer days, e.g. adding one month to 31st October or 31st January.

Comment: damn, you're right. this is why dealing with dates is so tough.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking to solve the related problem of finding the date for the first of the following month, **regardless** of the day in the given date. This does not find the same day 1 month later.

So, if all you want is to put in December 12, 2014 (or any day in December) and get back January 1, 2015, try this:

```
import datetime

def get_next_month(date):
    month = (date.month % 12) + 1
    year = date.year + (date.month + 1 > 12)
    return datetime.datetime(year, month, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution without the use of calendar:

```
def add_month_year(date, years=0, months=0):
    year, month = date.year + years, date.month + months + 1
    dyear, month = divmod(month - 1, 12)
    rdate = datetime.date(year + dyear, month + 1, 1) - datetime.timedelta(1)
    return rdate.replace(day = min(rdate.day, date.day))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_month(d,n=1): return type(d)(d.year+(d.month+n-1)/12, (d.month+n-1)%12+1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Use This:

```
import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.today()
nextMonthDatetime = today + datetime.timedelta(days=(today.max.day - today.day)+1)
```

Comment: max.day seems to always return 31
<code>
ipdb> start_date
datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 14, 0, 0)
ipdb> start_date.max.day
31
</code>

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with

```
from calendar  import monthrange

def same_day_months_after(start_date, months=1):
    target_year = start_date.year + ((start_date.month + months) / 12)
    target_month = (start_date.month + months) % 12
    num_days_target_month = monthrange(target_year, target_month)[1]
    return start_date.replace(year=target_year, month=target_month, 
        day=min(start_date.day, num_days_target_month))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def month_sub(year, month, sub_month):
    result_month = 0
    result_year = 0
    if month > (sub_month % 12):
        result_month = month - (sub_month % 12)
        result_year = year - (sub_month / 12)
    else:
        result_month = 12 - (sub_month % 12) + month
        result_year = year - (sub_month / 12 + 1)
    return (result_year, result_month)

def month_add(year, month, add_month):
    return month_sub(year, month, -add_month)

>>> month_add(2015, 7, 1)                        
(2015, 8)
>>> month_add(2015, 7, 20)
(2017, 3)
>>> month_add(2015, 7, 12)
(2016, 7)
>>> month_add(2015, 7, 24)
(2017, 7)
>>> month_add(2015, 7, -2)
(2015, 5)
>>> month_add(2015, 7, -12)
(2014, 7)
>>> month_add(2015, 7, -13)
(2014, 6)
```

Answer (score -3):

example using the time object:

```
start_time = time.gmtime(time.time())    # start now

#increment one month
start_time = time.gmtime(time.mktime([start_time.tm_year, start_time.tm_mon+1, start_time.tm_mday, start_time.tm_hour, start_time.tm_min, start_time.tm_sec, 0, 0, 0]))
```

Comment: Well, that's a PHP-like solution if I've ever seen one

Answer (score -5):

My very simple solution, which doesn't require any additional modules:

```
def addmonth(date):
    if date.day < 20:
        date2 = date+timedelta(32)
    else :
        date2 = date+timedelta(25)
    date2.replace(date2.year, date2.month, day)
    return date2
```

Comment: im sorry, this answer adds no value. the question is alraedy solved, and as far as i can see, this answer is wrong.