# How to get date range at now to end of the month?

Tags: python, python-datetime

I use datetime, i have:

```
delta = ((datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)) - datetime.timedelta(???)).isoformat()
```

I need replace ??? with day to end of the month.

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import datetime

d = datetime.date(2013,12,8)

last_day = datetime.date(d.year, (d.month+1)%12, 1) - datetime.timedelta(1,0,0)
```

Comment: Author/editor didn't notice this breaks for November: if d.month == 11, then (11 + 1) % 12 = 0, but the month value must be between 1 and 12. Don't think there's a nice way around this other than an ugly if-branch or obfuscated oneliner.

Answer (score 5):

To compute the end-of-the-current-month date, take the first of the current month, add 1 month and subtract 1 day.  For example, for 28 September, you'll end up with

```
1 September + 1 month = 1 October
1 October - 1 day = 30 September.
```

Comment: But hot to do it using datetime? I have datetime format data in variable

Answer (score 0):

To properly deal with dates around a new year, I found [dateutil.relativedelta](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-ba5ffd4df8111d1b83fc194b97ebecf837add454) to be a better alternative.

See also [How to increment datetime month in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130922/how-to-increment-datetime-month-in-python).

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

d = datetime.date(2013,12,8)

last_day = datetime.date(d.year, d.month, 1)+relativedelta(months=1, days=-1)
```