# Python : How to add month to December 2012 and get January 2013?

Tags: python, date, calendar

```
>>> start_date = date(1983, 11, 23)
>>> start_date.replace(month=start_date.month+1)
datetime.date(1983, 12, 23)
```

This works until the month is `<=11`, as soon as I do

```
>>> start_date = date(1983, 12, 23)
>>> start_date.replace(month=start_date.month+1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: month must be in 1..12
```

How can I keep adding months which increments the year when new month is added to December?

Comment: It is am implementation based on the Mayan calendar, and trying to go over dec/2012 overflows into the beginning of the cycle.  (Sorry could not miss the joke)

Comment: your joke is bad, and you should feel bad!

Comment: What happens if you are on December 31st, and you add two months? Do you want February 31st? February 28th (assuming not a leap year)? March 1st?

Comment: I did not think about this, but yes, you are right, I should be March 1st

Comment: So in other words, you want it to be the same day, and if that day is not valid, go to the first of the next month?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to increment datetime month in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130922/how-to-increment-datetime-month-in-python)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) library is useful for calculations like that:

```
>>> start_date + relativedelta(months=2)
datetime.date(1984, 1, 23)
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know about that! Should have used that myself instead of reinventing the wheel a while ago.

Comment: Thanks, so handy and awesome, thanks for telling about this @Daniel

Comment: Meanwhile, it has also been published to pip:

    pip install python-dateutil

Answer (score 5):

Using [`datetime.timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) and [`calendar.monthrange`](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange):

```
>>> from datetime import date, timedelta
>>> import calendar
>>> start_date = date(1983, 12, 23)
>>> days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(start_date.year, start_date.month)[1]
>>> start_date + timedelta(days=days_in_month)
datetime.date(1984, 1, 23)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
try:
    start_date.replace(month=start_date.month+1)
except ValueError:
    if start_date.month == 12:
         start_date.replace(month=1)
         start_date.replace(year=start_date.year+1)
    else:
         raise
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a more general solution for this problem, e.g. adding days, months and years mixed to one date:

```
import time, datetime, calendar
def upcount(dt, years=0, months=0, **kwargs):
    if months:
        total_months = dt.month + months
        month_years, months = divmod(total_months, 12)
        if months == 0:
            month_years -= 1
            months = 12
        years += month_years
    else:
        months = dt.month

    years = dt.year + years
    try:
        dt = dt.replace(year=years, month=months)
    except ValueError:
        # 31st march -> 31st april gives this error
        max_day = calendar.monthrange(years, months)[1]
        dt = dt.replace(year=years, month=months, day=max_day)

    if kwargs:
        dt += datetime.timedelta(**kwargs)
    return dt
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to decide how you want to deal with the weird cases like Jan 31 + 1 month = Feb 31 (which doesn't exist).  But I'd lean towards using timedelta to add to your date as in:

```
import datetime as dt
dt.datetime.now() + dt.timedelta(days=30)
```

Where you could choose days based on the size of the current or next month, or some such other value so you don't overflow the next month.