# How do I find the nth day of the next month in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to get the date `delta` by subtracting today's date from the `nth` day of the next month.

```
delta = nth_of_next_month - todays_date
print delta.days
```

**How do you get the date object for the 1st (or 2nd, 3rd.. nth) day of the next month.** I tried taking the month number from the date object and increasing it by 1. Which is obviously a dumb idea because 12 + 1 = 13. I also tried adding one month to today and tried to get to the first of the month. I am sure that there is a much more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: I'd imagine all you need to do is increment the month property of the date object. This previous answer shows how since the month property is not writable http://stackoverflow.com/a/4131114/333082

Comment: Why do you care about "more efficient" here? The obvious and simple implementation in sunshine's answer takes only 0.46us to do all that "expensive" work, compared to 1.64us to call `now()`. So I highly doubt it will be a bottleneck in your code. The simplest implementation—one that you understand, and can debug easily—is better than the fastest one, unless it's affecting your total runtime.

Comment: @abarnert exactly what I meant... Efficient to me.  Not computing power.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `dateutil` library is useful for this:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import datetime

# Where day is the day you want in the following month
dt = datetime.now() + relativedelta(months=1, day=20)
```

Comment: http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-6a1472b7c74e5b8bab7784f11214250d34e09aa5 explains what is going on with relativedelta

Answer (score 6):

This should be straightforward unless I'm missing something in your question:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
nth_day = 5
next_month = now.month + 1 if now.month < 12 else 1 # February
year = now.year if now.month < 12 else now.year+1
nth_of_next_month = datetime.datetime(year, next_month, nth_day)
print(nth_of_next_month)
```

Result:

```
2014-02-05 00:00:00
```

Using `dateutil` as suggested in another answer is a much better idea than this, though.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to use [delorean](http://delorean.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) library:

> Delorean is a library that provides easy and convenient datetime
>   conversions in Python.

```
>>> from delorean import Delorean
>>> d = Delorean()
>>> d.next_month()
Delorean(datetime=2014-02-15 18:51:14.325350+00:00, timezone=UTC)
>>> d.next_month().next_day(2)
Delorean(datetime=2014-02-17 18:51:14.325350+00:00, timezone=UTC)
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach to calculating the next month without external libraries:

```
def nth_day_of_next_month(dt, n):
    return dt.replace(
        year=dt.year + (dt.month // 12),  # +1 for december, +0 otherwise
        month=(dt.month % 12) + 1,        # december becomes january
        day=n)
```

This works for both `datetime.datetime()` and `datetime.date()` objects.

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> def nth_day_of_next_month(dt, n):
...     return dt.replace(year=dt.year + (dt.month // 12), month=(dt.month % 12) + 1, day=n)
... 
>>> nth_day_of_next_month(datetime.datetime.now(), 4)
datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 4, 19, 20, 51, 177860)
>>> nth_day_of_next_month(datetime.date.today(), 18)
datetime.date(2014, 2, 18)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using any external library, this can be achived as follows

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def nth_day_of_next_month(n):
    today = datetime.now()
    next_month_dt = today + timedelta(days=32-today.day)
    return next_month_dt.replace(day=n)
```