# Iterating over date in python

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
MYDATE = []
start_date = "2011-01-01"
stop_date = "2013-05-01"

start = start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
stop = stop_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
for r in .......:
    MYDATE.append((r,r))
```

How can I iterate over Date betweet `start_date` and `stop_date`?

Comment: Using what interval? Years, months, days, seconds? Bit more info needed I think.

Comment: I'd just add 1 month to the start date inside a `while` loop e.g. `while newdate < stop:` I don't know if there's an easy way to add months, but I did see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130922/how-to-increment-datetime-month-in-python

Comment: See this old question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060279/iterating-through-a-range-of-dates-in-python

Comment: How do you manage to use `strftime()` on a string object?

Comment: Also related: [How to increment datetime month in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130922/how-to-increment-datetime-month-in-python)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well it depends on how you wish to iterate. By days? by months? Using [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) will solve your problem.

```
from datetime import datetime

start_date = "2011-01-01"
stop_date = "2013-05-01"

start = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
stop = datetime.strptime(stop_date, "%Y-%m-%d")

from datetime import timedelta
while start < stop:
    start = start + timedelta(days=1)  # increase day one by one
```

Another approach to itearete through months is using [`relativedelta`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-ba5ffd4df8111d1b83fc194b97ebecf837add454)

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
start = start + relativedelta(months = +1)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)?

```
start = datetime.now()
end = start + timedelta(days=10)

tmp = start

while tmp < end:
    print tmp
    tmp = tmp + timedelta(days=1) # replace the interval at will
```

prints

```
2014-04-07 10:42:14.943790
2014-04-08 10:42:14.943790
2014-04-09 10:42:14.943790
2014-04-10 10:42:14.943790
2014-04-11 10:42:14.943790
2014-04-12 10:42:14.943790
2014-04-13 10:42:14.943790
2014-04-14 10:42:14.943790
2014-04-15 10:42:14.943790
2014-04-16 10:42:14.943790
```

Comment: This does not answer the question as the frequency required is monthly and timedelta does not support month according to the documentation