# How do I filter a queryset to dates within the next x months?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model called Post with an attribute date.

I want to filter the queryset so that I retrieve posts only in the next x months. e.g. next 3 months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
import calendar

    def add_months(sourcedate, months):
         month = sourcedate.month - 1 + months
         year = sourcedate.year + month / 12
         month = month % 12 + 1
         day = min(sourcedate.day, calendar.monthrange(year,month)[1])
         return datetime.date(year, month, day)


    today = datetime.today()
    table_name.objects.filter(date__range=[str(today.date()), str(add_months(today, 3).date())])
```

**Reference**
 - [How to increment datetime by custom months in python without using library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130922/how-to-increment-datetime-month-in-python)
 - [Django database query: How to filter objects by date range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668619/django-database-query-how-to-filter-objects-by-date-range)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`range`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#range). Build the date and pass to the QuerySet. [Relevant SO question for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668619/django-database-query-how-to-filter-objects-by-date-range).