# How to convert it into month/year format from integer value

Tags: python

I have date step like below

```
710040,  710784,  711456,  712200,  712920,  713664,
714384,  715128,  715872,  716592,  717336,  718056,
718800,  719544,  720216,  720960,  721680,  722424
```

This is a monthly dataset so date steps are month of different year. First one is Jan,1970
I want to convert it into month/year format.

Comment: What is your question about this task?

Comment: How to convert from this integer value to date format

Comment: How does the number 710040 relate to January 1970? Which month is 710784 supposed to be?

Comment: What was the problem when you wrote the code to do what you want?

Comment: 710784 should be feb'1970. 710040 is jan,1970 I know another programm.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35066588/is-there-a-simple-way-to-increment-a-datetime-object-one-month-in-python/35067328

Comment: Do you have an explanation as to why, 710040 = January 1970, 710784 = February 1970, etc. ?

Comment: Please show us what have you tried until now

Answer (score 0):

Do these numbers correspond to sequential months? If so you can create a mapping using a dictionary.

Here I am using `datetime(year, month, day).strftime(format)` to get "Jan, 1970" type strings.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> l = [710040,  710784,  711456,  712200,  712920,  713664,
... 714384,  715128,  715872,  716592,  717336,  718056,
... 718800,  719544,  720216,  720960,  721680,  722424]
>>> mapping = {
...     num : datetime(1970 + i // 12, i%12 + 1, 1).strftime('%b, %Y')
...     for i, num in enumerate(l)
... }
```

which gives

```
>>> mapping
{710040: 'Jan, 1970', 710784: 'Feb, 1970', 711456: 'Mar, 1970', 712200: 'Apr, 1970', 712920: 'May, 1970', 713664: 'Jun, 1970', 714384: 'Jul, 1970', 715128: 'Aug, 1970', 715872: 'Sep, 1970', 716592: 'Oct, 1970', 717336: 'Nov, 1970', 718056: 'Dec, 1970', 718800: 'Jan, 1971', 719544: 'Feb, 1971', 720216: 'Mar, 1971', 720960: 'Apr, 1971', 721680: 'May, 1971', 722424: 'Jun, 1971'}
```