# How to use dateutil.relativedelta in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-dateutil

Hello I am trying to use `relativedelta` from the `dateutil` module.

I want to do what is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130922/how-to-increment-datetime-by-custom-months-in-python-without-using-library), add some months to a given `datetime` object.

But I'm trying to use Python 3 for this and I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/controller.py", line 2, in <module>
    from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
ImportError: No module named 'dateutil'
```

I then read that dateutil is now part of Python 3 but how do I import it?
`import dateutil` does not seem to work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/controller.py", line 3, in <module>
    import dateutil
ImportError: No module named 'dateutil'
```

I am using a virtualenv so I would like to install it with `pip`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems you have to pip-install it like this and it works :

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

Comment: Why is it `python-dateutil` and not `dateutil` ?

Comment: Because it's the name of the package. It works like this, isn't it ?

Comment: Yeah, it does but I tried `pip install dateutil` before asking here. Had I known it was `python-dateutil`, my question wouldn't have been necessary :).

Answer (score 5):

You need to install it first using `pip3 install python-dateutil`. It's not included by default with Python 3, I don't know where you read that.

I added a `pip3` and not just plain old `pip` because that will install it specifically for Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

Open up your console and type: `pip install python-dateutil`

Answer (score 1):

If you have both `python2.X` and `python3.X` installed than you can use `sudo python3 -m pip install python-dateutil`