# How to add 1 month to current time in Python using only datetime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I came up with some ideas how to add 30 days. But code should add 31 days if this month has 31 days or 28 , for example,  if it is Febuary. The only library that should be used is **datetime**.
This is what i came with.

```
 def get_next_month(date):
   month = (date.month % 12) + 1
   year = date.year + (date.month + 1 > 12)
   datetime.datetime(year, month, 1)
```

But it's not completely correct(

Comment: you can use [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/4131114/302264 for an answer that seems to correctly solve the problem using only built-in Python libraries (it does use `calendar` though, which was not included in your request).