# how to set date variables in python in different formats?

Tags: python, datetime

My code starts off by setting these 3 variables

```
var1 = 'Sep20'
var2 = '2020 09'
var3 = '2020-10-01'
```

How do I code such that var2 and var3 are functions of var1, so that I only have to set 1 variable? I would like to enter a string value for var1 and have var2 & var3 automatically calculated

Another example for a different month:

```
var1 = 'Dec20'      # a given month MMM YY
var2 = '2020 12'    # the same month YYYY MM
var3 = '2021-01-01' # the first day of the NEXT month YYYY-MM-DD
```

Comment: Take a look at `datetime.datetime.strptime` and `datetime.datetime.strftime`

Comment: Specifically look at the documentation for [`strftime()` and `strptime()` Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

Comment: thanks i got part way there using these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this quite nicely with `datetime`

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

d = date(2020, 12, 1)
var1 = d.strftime("%b%y")
var2 = d.strftime("%Y %m")
nextd = d + relativedelta(months=1)
var3 = nextd.strftime("%Y-%m-01")
```

See [here for more info about relativedelta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15155212/1197540), and see [here for more info about strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Comment: i figured out `var1` & `var2` but did not know how to get to `var3`. thanks for the tip on `relativedelta`!

Answer (score 0):

The minimal example below relies on dateutil package:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta

def date_func(year, month, day):
    x = datetime(year,month,day)
    first_next_month = x + relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1, day=1)
    
    return [
        x.strftime('%b%y'),
        x.strftime('%Y %m'),
        first_next_month.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    ]
```