# How do I add a month to my date object in datetime? Python

Tags: python, datetime

I need to create a day variable which will store the current date, and I need another variable which will store the deadline(day + 1 month), but I seem to be doing something wrong.

```
import datetime

day = datetime.date.today()
deadline = datetime.date.today()
deadline.month += 1

print(day)
print(deadline)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I calculate the date six months from the current date using the datetime Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546321/how-do-i-calculate-the-date-six-months-from-the-current-date-using-the-datetime)

Comment: How do you want it to react if the next month is short? For example `2021-01-31` plus one month?

Answer (score 15):

documentation : https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

day = datetime.date.today()
# day --> datetime.date(2021, 1, 8)


deadline = day + relativedelta(months=1)
# deadline --> datetime.date(2021, 2, 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try importing [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) and use `relativedelta` to achieve what you want. You could refer to this 
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130922/how-to-increment-datetime-by-custom-months-in-python-without-using-library) for more info

```
deadline = day + relativedelta(months=1)
```

Comment: from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

Comment: https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html