# How to get 1st calendar day of the current and next month based on a current date variable

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime

I have a date variable calls today_date as below. I need to get the 1st calendar day of the current and next month.
In my case, today_date is 4/17/2021, I need to create two more variables calls first_day_current which should be 4/1/2021, and first_day_next which should be 5/1/2021.
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

```
import datetime as dt    
today_date
'2021-04-17'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the last day of the month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/how-to-get-the-last-day-of-the-month)

Comment: I believe this will answer your questions see [How to get the last day of the month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/how-to-get-the-last-day-of-the-month)

Comment: first day of the month is easy, just replace the day with 1. first day of *next* month: add a [relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) of one month and *then* replace day with 1.

Comment: Thanks @itprorh66, I try to avoid hard coding like manually input the date in the month range. The goal is to get all the dates based on the global variable/parameter in the program, but thanks for the ideas.

Comment: Thanks @MrFuppes for the ideas. Really appreciated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out pd.offsets could accomplish this task as below -

```
import datetime as dt 
import pandas as pd

today_date #'2021-04-17' this is a variable that is being created in the program
first_day_current = today_date.replace(day=1) # this will be 2021-04-01
next_month = first_day_current + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(n=1)
first_day_next = next_month.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') # this will be 2021-05-01
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting just the first date of a month is quite simple - since it equals `1` all the time. You can even do this without needing the `datetime` module to simplify calculations for you, if `today_date` is always a string `"Year-Month-Day"` (or any consistent format - parse it accordingly)

```py
today_date = '2021-04-17'
y, m, d = today_date.split('-')
first_day_current = f"{y}-{m}-01"
y, m = int(y), int(m)
first_day_next = f"{y+(m==12)}-{m%12+1}-01"
```

If you want to use `datetime.date()`, then you'll anyway have to convert the string to (year, month, date) `int`s to give as arguments (or do `today_date = datetime.date.today()`.
Then `.replace(day=1)` to get first_day_current.
`datetime.timedelta` can't add months (only upto weeks), so you'll need to use [other libraries for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130922/how-to-increment-datetime-by-custom-months-in-python-without-using-library). But it's more imports and calculations to do the same thing in effect.

Comment: Thanks @gdcodes for the ideas, this is very helpful.