# Increasing Number Decreasing Date Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, date

Need Help, I'm trying to get a Date column based on user input it will decrease the current date with one month interval with increase in Total Age column Number.

```
CurrentDf = {
  "VIN": ['v1','v1','v1','v2','v2','v2','v2','v3','v3','v3'],
  "Total Age": [10,10,10, 08,08,08,08,11,11,11],
  "Months": [05,07,09,01,06,07,08,02,05,07],
  "Monthly Revenue": [1108,4330,7121,1998,1783,9628, 2082,8763,5683, 5780]
}

Total_Age = [int(x) for x in input('Please enter Total Age?= ').split(',')]
```

CurrentDf:

| VIN | Total Age | Months | Monthly Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| v1 | 10 | 05 | 1108 |
| v1 | 10 | 07 | 4330 |
| v1 | 10 | 09 | 7121 |
| v2 | 08 | 01 | 1998 |
| v2 | 08 | 06 | 1783 |
| v2 | 08 | 07 | 9628 |
| v2 | 08 | 08 | 2082 |
| v3 | 11 | 02 | 8763 |
| v3 | 11 | 05 | 5683 |
| v3 | 11 | 07 | 5780 |

UserInput: [8]

outputDF:

| VIN | Total Age | Months | Monthly Revenue | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| v1 | 10 | 05 | 1108 | 2022-04-01 |
| v1 | 10 | 07 | 4330 | 2022-04-01 |
| v1 | 10 | 09 | 7121 | 2022-04-01 |
| v2 | 08 | 01 | 1998 | 2022-05-01 |
| v2 | 08 | 06 | 1783 | 2022-05-01 |
| v2 | 08 | 07 | 9628 | 2022-05-01 |
| v2 | 08 | 08 | 2082 | 2022-05-01 |
| v3 | 11 | 02 | 8763 | 2022-03-01 |
| v3 | 11 | 05 | 5683 | 2022-03-01 |
| v3 | 11 | 07 | 5780 | 2022-03-01 |

Comment: What do you mean by "decrease the current date with one month interval with increase in Total Age column Number"? The "Total Age" column in your expected output is the same as your input

Comment: yess @not_speshal

Comment: Please explain your "Date" column in your expected output. Your question is not clear.

Comment: If you are having an issue with the datetime module, then you may want to look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130922/how-to-increment-datetime-by-custom-months-in-python-without-using-library

Comment: If the userInput is 8 it should add current date in all the row where Total age is "8" & have one month interval with current date where Total Age age is 9 & so on @not_speshal

Comment: You have one month interval where Total Age is 10 and not 9 (there is no 9 in your dataframe).

Comment: @not_speshal
whatever the next number is after 8

Comment: Provide a better example. What if user enters 9? What if the ages in your dataframe are 5, 9, 24? Explain the *general* logic and not for a specific case.

Comment: Could you please fix the [minial, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please? When I use your code, your values (08,02, ...) produce a SyntaxError: invalid token. Also, add the imports for pandas.

Comment: @not_speshal
Total Age is alway going to b in increasing order, In other words we can say userinput is going to b the smallest number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, try ranking the ages to produce the desired month offset:

```
input_age = int(input('Please enter Total Age?= '))

df["Date"] = df["Total Age"].astype(int).sub(input_age).rank(method='dense').apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp.today().date()-pd.DateOffset(months=x-1))
```

###### Output with `input_age` = 8:

```
>>> df
  VIN Total Age Months  Monthly Revenue       Date
0  v1        10     05             1108 2022-04-01
1  v1        10     07             4330 2022-04-01
2  v1        10     09             7121 2022-04-01
3  v2        08     01             1998 2022-05-01
4  v2        08     06             1783 2022-05-01
5  v2        08     07             9628 2022-05-01
6  v2        08     08             2082 2022-05-01
7  v3        11     02             8763 2022-03-01
8  v3        11     05             5683 2022-03-01
9  v3        11     07             5780 2022-03-01
```

###### Input df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"VIN": ['v1','v1','v1','v2','v2','v2','v2','v3','v3','v3'],
                   "Total Age": ['10','10','10','08','08','08','08','11','11','11'],
                   "Months": ['05','07','09','01','06','07','08','02','05','07'],
                   "Monthly Revenue": [1108,4330,7121,1998,1783,9628, 2082,8763,5683, 5780]
                   })
```

Comment: " Lengths must be equal" @not_speshal getting error

Comment: No idea where or how you're getting that error. This works on the example df you provided.

Comment: might be because my UserInput is in list @not_speshal

Comment: Then use `Total_Age[0]` or get the input like I do. Why do you need a list?

Comment: actually UserInput mandate to be in list so that it can take multi value as well..it will be great help if you can just edit ur response accordingly @not_speshal

Comment: I already told you. Use `Total_Age[0]`. Makes no sense that the input is a list considering you're using a single number "8"